# Align over many rows in table

Tags: tables, align

How can I do an alignment with the `=` characters for `a=1`, `abbbbbb=5` and `csf=6` ?

It should look like this but inside the table:

```
      a=1
abbbbbb=5234
    csf=6
```

My code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{4pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}




\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{a } & looooooooooong \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}[6]{*}{c} & a=1  \\
    \cline{2-2}          & abbbbbb=5234  \\
    \cline{2-2}          & csf = 6  \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

What I tried (but didn't work):

```
   \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{flowchart}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\setlength{\heavyrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\abovetopsep}{4pt}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{a } & looooooooooong \\
        \hline
        \multirow{3}[6]{*}{c} &\begin{align} a&=1  \\
        \cline{2-2}          & abbbbbb&=5234  \\
        \cline{2-2}          & csf &= 6 \end{align} \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

I hope someone can help me. I searched a bit in the forums but it all the solution seem to be so complicated for a quite simple problem like this. Also it's Tex so there should be a nice analytic solution I hope cause I need this feature quite often in my tables.

Comment: Use two columns: {r@{=}l}

Comment: hello thank you for your answer. i'm quite a beginner. Can you specify what you mean?
So there no way of using a classic `align`enviroment?

Comment: why do you want the equations in a table? it seems a slightly odd requirement.

Comment: you could have an align inside the table but (most easily) without the horizontal rules, do you need the rules? If the equations are related and need alignment you wouldn't normally put in rules to separate them.

Comment: @David Carlisle no i don't need them.
I want to write a protokoll Specification. There need to be one colummn in one row which contains about 4 rows (`\multirow`) where i'll write in the first row 1=`message`, in the second row 2=`information`. `message` and `information`will have different widths and since it the rows will be under each other it looks bad if i don't align them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following solution is a refinement of @JohnKormylo's suggestion: change the tabular setup from 2 to 3 columns, and have LaTeX insert `=` (type mathrel, in math mode) automatically between columns 2 and 3. That way, the spacing around the `=` symbol will automatically be appropriate for math-mode material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath,multirow}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{| c | r @{${}={}$} l |}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{a} & \mc{looooooooooong} \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{cc} & a       & 1    \\ \cline{2-3}            
                       & abbbbbb & 5234 \\ \cline{2-3}            
                       & csf     & 6    \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beat me by 4 miniuts!

Answer (score 4):

How about a solution with only two rows, and an `aligned` environment? For the horizontal rules inside the aligned environment, I use the capability of `\cmidrule` to extend on both sides with the `(lr)` argument. This is obtained with a rather simple code. The 0.95em lengthening of `\cmidrule` was found by trial and error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering\setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\begin{tabular}{| c |c|}
\hline
a & looooooooooong\\ \hline
c & $\begin{aligned} a & = 1 \\
\cmidrule(l{-0.95em} r{-0.95em}){1-3}
                       abbbbbb & = 5234 \\
\cmidrule(l{-0.95em} r{-0.95em}){1-3}
                       csf & = 6 \end{aligned}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the benefit of readers who maybe aren't all that familiar with the facilities of the `booktabs` package, could you add a brief description of how you came up with `-0.95em` as the length value to be passed to the trimming options of `\cmidrule`?

Comment: @Mico: Done, mylord! The sole benefit, I think, will be to understand what `l{some length}` and `r{some length}` mean in the syntax of `\cmidrule`.

Comment: Thank you this is what i was searching originally for :) I'll still stick with the three column version cause on the right side of the equal i will write a word and therefor non italic or `\verb||`style looks better

Comment: You can write  words with `\text{some words}` or `\texttt` inside math mode…

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways using overlapping of content (since it looks like it should be math, I've used `\mathllap` and `\mathrlap` from [`mathtools`](//ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)), or boxing them into similar-sized boxes (using [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  a & looooooooooong   \\
  \hline
    & $a = 1$          \\
  \cline{2-2}
    & $abbbbbb = 5234$ \\
  \cline{2-2}
  c & $csf = 6$        \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} \qquad
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  a & looooooooooong   \\
  \hline
    & $\phantom{abbbbbb}\mathllap{a} = \mathrlap{1}\phantom{5234}$   \\
  \cline{2-2}
    & $abbbbbb = 5234$ \\
  \cline{2-2}
  c & $\phantom{abbbbbb}\mathllap{csf} = \mathrlap{6}\phantom{5234}$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabular} \qquad
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  a & looooooooooong   \\
  \hline
    & $\eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$a$} = \eqmakebox[rhs][l]{$1$}$    \\
  \cline{2-2}
    & $\eqmakebox[lhs]{$abbbbbb$} = \eqmakebox[rhs]{$5234$}$ \\
  \cline{2-2}
  c & $\eqmakebox[lhs][r]{$csf$} = \eqmakebox[rhs][l]{$6$}$  \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) i'll stick with the other three column answer cause it fits my needs best