# aligning typewriter text in different rows

Tags: color, text, typewriter

I am putting together a table with letters, and numbers below the letters to track progress.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor, placeins, cmbright}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
S & \texttt{\textcolor{gray}{E}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{teal}{M}\textcolor{teal}{W}\textcolor{green}{D}\textcolor{gray}{T}\textcolor{green}{K}\textcolor{teal}{K}\textcolor{teal}{E}\textcolor{green}{V}\textcolor{gray}{K}\textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{M}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{teal}{K}\textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{teal}{E}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{teal}{V}\textcolor{gray}{D}\textcolor{green}{N}\textcolor{teal}{K}\textcolor{green}{D}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{gray}{E}\textcolor{teal}{R}\textcolor{teal}{F}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{green}{P}\textcolor{gray}{S}\textcolor{teal}{L}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{teal}{Q}\textcolor{teal}{C}\textcolor{gray}{I}\textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{D}\textcolor{green}{P}\textcolor{teal}{T}E-\textcolor{gray}{-}\textcolor{teal}{V}\textcolor{teal}{P}\textcolor{teal}{E}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{gray}{V}\textcolor{teal}{H}\textcolor{teal}{L}\textcolor{green}{L}\textcolor{teal}{G}\textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{green}{T}\textcolor{green}{T}\textcolor{green}{F}\textcolor{green}{V}\textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{teal}{E}\textcolor{green}{V}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{teal}{P}\textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{green}{L}\textcolor{teal}{S}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{gray}{M}\textcolor{teal}{V}\textcolor{green}{P}\textcolor{teal}{L}\textcolor{green}{L}\textcolor{gray}{S}\textcolor{teal}{R}\textcolor{teal}{G}\textcolor{green}{L}\textcolor{teal}{N}\textcolor{gray}{E}\textcolor{teal}{R}E\textcolor{teal}{-}T-\textcolor{teal}{-}\textcolor{teal}{G}\textcolor{gray}{I}\textcolor{teal}{K}\textcolor{green}{R}\textcolor{teal}{K}\textcolor{teal}{S}\textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{teal}{V}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{teal}{D}} & 270
\\
S track & \texttt{176   -181   -186   -191   -196   -201   -206   -211   -216   ---221   -226   -231   -236   -241   -246   -251   -256   --259   -264   -269} & 270
\\
\hline\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following:

[image]

but as you can see, the text in both columns doesn't align.

To be clear, `1` should be directly below the `E` above.  However, it's shifted slightly to the left.  The `269` is also showing up in the wrong spot.

The problem is that spaces are being treated differently, even with the monospace `\texttt`

I have tried solutions from many different places, such as [Align over many rows in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/393589/align-over-many-rows-in-table) (not the only place) but I cannot see how to get the numbers to align.

I've tried making the letters and numbers into a 100-column-wide cell in the large table, but there was too much space in between the letters, and the table became unreadable.

I've also tried `flushleft` but that failed.

Is there some way that I can tell LaTeX, put the `1` directly below the `E`?

I had some luck with using `l` on the center column, but that doesn't seem to work with the right side of the center column.

I'm open to a complete redesign as long as the finished product looks good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have the same number of elements in the two rows which is the main cause in the misalignment; there are 100 characters in the first line, and 101 in the second line (if you include the spaces). Here's a verbatim visual:

```
ETMWDTKKEVKAAATAAMTKATETVDNKDIERFIPSLIQCIADPTE--VPETVHLLGATTFVAEVTPATLSIMVPLLSRGLNERE-T--GIKRKSAVIID
176 -181 -186 -191 -196 -201 -206 -211 -216 ---221 -226 -231 -236 -241 -246 -251 -256 --259 -264 -269
```

It's best to rewrite your code to be more legible, which would allow you to isolate the mistakes better. I'm unfamiliar with the content, so broke it into widths matching the numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor, cmbright}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\small
\begin{tabular}{ | c | l | c | }
  \hline
  S & \ttfamily
      \textcolor{gray}{E}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{teal}{M}%
      \textcolor{teal}{W}\textcolor{green}{D}\textcolor{gray}{T}\textcolor{green}{K}%
      \textcolor{teal}{K}\textcolor{teal}{E}\textcolor{green}{V}\textcolor{gray}{K}%
      \textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{T}%
      \textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{M}\textcolor{teal}{T}%
      \textcolor{teal}{K}\textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{teal}{E}%
      \textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{teal}{V}\textcolor{gray}{D}\textcolor{green}{N}%
      \textcolor{teal}{K}\textcolor{green}{D}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{gray}{E}%
      \textcolor{teal}{R}\textcolor{teal}{F}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{green}{P}%
      \textcolor{gray}{S}\textcolor{teal}{L}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{teal}{Q}%
      \textcolor{teal}{C}\textcolor{gray}{I}\textcolor{teal}{A}\textcolor{teal}{D}%
      \textcolor{green}{P}\textcolor{teal}{T}E-%
      \textcolor{gray}{-}\textcolor{teal}{V}\textcolor{teal}{P}\textcolor{teal}{E}%
      \textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{gray}{V}\textcolor{teal}{H}\textcolor{teal}{L}%
      \textcolor{green}{L}\textcolor{teal}{G}\textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{green}{T}%
      \textcolor{green}{T}\textcolor{green}{F}\textcolor{green}{V}\textcolor{gray}{A}%
      \textcolor{teal}{E}\textcolor{green}{V}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{teal}{P}%
      \textcolor{gray}{A}\textcolor{teal}{T}\textcolor{green}{L}\textcolor{teal}{S}%
      \textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{gray}{M}\textcolor{teal}{V}\textcolor{green}{P}%
      \textcolor{teal}{L}\textcolor{green}{L}\textcolor{gray}{S}\textcolor{teal}{R}%
      \textcolor{teal}{G}\textcolor{green}{L}\textcolor{teal}{N}\textcolor{gray}{E}%
      \textcolor{teal}{R}E\textcolor{teal}{-}T%
      -\textcolor{teal}{-}\textcolor{teal}{G}\textcolor{gray}{I}\textcolor{teal}{K}%
      \textcolor{green}{R}\textcolor{teal}{K}\textcolor{teal}{S}\textcolor{gray}{A}%
      \textcolor{teal}{V}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{teal}{I}\textcolor{teal}{D} & 270 \\
  S track & \ttfamily
      176~%
      -181~%
      -186~%
      -191~%
      -196~%
      -201~%
      -206~%
      -211~%
      -216~%
      ---221~%
      -226~%
      -231~%
      -236~%
      -241~%
      -246~%
      -251~%
      -256~%
      --259~%
      -264~%
      -269 & 270 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```